# How can i call a C# server side function on click of asp:navigationmenu item?

Tags: asp.net

I am using a function for logout of client in asp.net C# previously i was using asp.net button's click event for calling it but now i want to call it from one of navigation menu item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to set a page that when requested logs the user out then redirects them to the login screen, that way you can create a simple static `<a href="#">` to the page and it'll work regardless of where you put it.

You can actually reuse your existing Login page logic, but make the logout action be done by querystring. Like so:

```
<a runat="server" href="~\Path\To\Login.aspx?logout=1">Logout</a>
```

In your LoginPage class:

```
public override void OnLoad(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

    if( Request.QueryString["logout"] == "1" ) {

        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Response.Redirect("~\Path\To\Login.aspx");
    } else {
        if( Page.IsPostBack && (Page.Validate(), Page.IsValid ) ) {
             // your current login logic
        }
    }
}
```

HTH.

Comment: its not working for its not redirecting to another page
<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx?logout=1" Text="LOG-IN"/>

if( Request.QueryString["logout"] == "1" ) 
            {

                logout();
            }

Comment: tell me any other beeter method.

Comment: Can you post your entire *.aspx and code-behind code in your original question?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use an `asp:LinkButton` then, or just style your old button to look like a link?

**EDIT:** if you can use an anchor tag instead of that, then just do this: `<a href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(this.id, '');" ServerClick="YourEventWhereYouLogoutUser" />`

Comment: sorry but i am using navigation menu instead of button now